# Is it possible to check if an image is taken by camera or uploaded from photo library by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, camera

My intention is to force the mobile browser to open camera taking pictures instead of allowing users to upload images from photo library. Is it possible to disable the "upload from library" option on safari/chrome and show "use camera" only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me on my Galaxy S6. I can't speak to other Android devices.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
```

A side note -

If anyone comes here looking for an iOS solution to this problem, it looks like as of 5/10/2016, WebRTC is not supported for the Safari browser and it is not yet possible to disable the upload from library functionality. See this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518344/html5-safari-ios-access-only-camera-not-photo-library) article and related wiki page on the topic.